# Resizable divs using flex-box

Tags: javascript, html, angular, flexbox, css-grid

I have a page with 3 `div`s inside it, 2 of them should be resizable. All of them could be shifted left/right and could be maximized/minimized.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resizable-divs-9qrckz?file=src/app/app.component.html).

The problem is that sometimes the resizing is causing scrollbars to be shown when, for example, resizing the first box and dragging its handler to the right end of the screen.

Is there a way to achieve the same goal with flex box or css grid? Maybe increasing or decreasing the `flexGrow` depending on the mouse movement? Does this make sence?

Comment: not sure that it is a good solution but try to add to body overflow:hidden. And in general, take a look in this way of a solution. In your example, it fixed the issue. But check is it affecting any other pages on your website

Comment: @DmitriySakhno Overflow here will not help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reset default margin and padding?

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```